# Best way to check/know if build in Azure Devops is triggered by manually or CI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 repo, `source` and `target` for source there are 2 stages in the release pipeline . one is building the artifacts called `Dev` and then another is `trigger` => trigger the build pipeline for the `target` repo using api call. Both repos are in the same project.

It can be possible that `target repo` can be run manually run without continuous CI of `source-repo`.
Now my question is there any possibility to figure out how the build of `target-repo` initiated is it `manually` or `CI`?

[image: AzDo Pipeline]

Answer (score 5):

You have variable [`Build.Reason`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) which gives you

> The event that caused the build to run.

[image]

Comment: I know this should be the case, but for me when I checked I see buildReason in `target-repo` it shows `Manual`. Is it because I clicked manually the release of `Dev` stage from the source repo?

Comment: This is probably because there is no difference between clicking on the UI and running through API. At the end all calls are manual. What you can do is to create a variable on the pipeline and set it to default like UI, and change it triggering to API when you call API. In combination with Build.Reason you should get what you want.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think I can do that one and during the API call, I can update that release value. But apart from this let say I created a variable after the end of API call in my release of `trigger` now how can I access this output variable in my build of target-repo.  e.g. `echo "1.2.3" >> $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/version.env` now how can I download this `version.env` in my build process of `target`.

Comment: Do you use Release pipelines or YAML pipelines? And if you want to share a vriable between two pipelines this won't be easy. You can save variable as an artifact and then use this artifact in your target pipeline to recreate variable using logging command. Basically you need make an artifact for `version.env` and download it in your next pipeline.